# SOAP to REST conversion Java

Tags: java, rest, soap, esb

There are hundreds of SOAP web services need to convert to REST without using an ESB like WSO2 EI or Fuse. Are there any tool or library available to support for this conversion and to create a Spring Boot project ? Will it be useful to use wsdl2rest utility in this case ? In my understanding  wsdl2rest utility not anymore available as a standard distribution.

Comment: First, why do you need to convert SOAP to REST? Second, they are both fundamentally different even when they both build up on HTTP. The primer one is a RPC remote method invocation while the latter one exchanges documents and business rules triggered are just a side effect of the document management process. REST is build up on standardized protocols, media type formats and link-relations. A mapping from SOAP usually ends up in a pseudo-REST thing that is actually also RPC as well, so not a good idea in general unless you want to run into the same issues SOAP has on the long run

Comment: SOAP to REST conversion doing purely because of customer interest. No any other reason.

Comment: They do poorly because they serve two different purposes. As mentioned one is RPC the other one exactly the opposite. SOAP just uses HTTP for transporting messages via POST (with 1.2 GET could be used as well but is hardly used) without respecting the actual intentions of each of the methods. SOAP even comes with its own security bindings instead of reusing HTTPS and such. I don't see how a 1:1 conversion should be possible by default. I.e. SOAP clients are tailoremade for just one SOAP endpoint while a REST client (think of your browser) should be able to handle a plethora of servers